# ¿Como mostrar dos registros que tienen diferente fecha en una misma columna usando mysql?

Tags: mysql

Hola resulta que estoy practicando haciendo una especie de registro de horarios de trabajos. Entonces cree un form donde ingreso el nombre del empleado junto con una fecha - hora de ingreso y una fecha - hora de salida. En mysql se guarda asi.

| id | nombre | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan | 2023-01-11 05:00:00 |
| 2 | Juan | 2023-01-11 17:00:00 |

Ahora lo que intento es hacer una consulta donde me muestre en una sola fila todos los datos tanto la hora de entrada como salida

| id | nombre | Registro horario |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan | 2023-01-11 05:00:00 2023-01-11 17:00:00 |

Eh intentado usar group BY pero no consigo hacerlo. ¿Como podría lograr esto?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas se hace con un GROUP_CONCAT.
Te dejo aquí la documentación para que la leas y resuelvas tu problema.
Saludos.

[GROUP_CONCAT MYSQL](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: gracias con este creo que podre realizar lo que requiero.

Comment: Claro, si tienes dudas, por aquí te contesto :)

Answer (score 0):

por que no pruebas una solución mas sencilla, en tu tabla mysql tener el registro de ingreso y salida, así cuando consultes tus datos solo tienes que ir a 1 solo registro por trabajador, así puedes tener el registro del turno de cada día, creo que es mucho mas práctico, algo así?

[image: tabla turnos]

Comment: es verdad que hacerlo asi es lo mas facil, pero probe de esta manera por que queria ver si encontraba alguna manera de tratar de hacerlo.

Comment: genial, si claro siempre es bueno probar otras alternativas, justo como dice Rodrigo arriba, el GROUP_CONCAT viene perfecto